# Angular material poor performance, large memory footage and Memory Leak

Tags: angularjs, performance, memory-leaks, angular-material

Angular material poor performance and large memory footage:

`Issue:
When added md-input-container to a page, the number of $watchers increased from 6504 to
112507?, by total 17 times more than without the angular material tag*`
both md-input-container and $mdDialog cause memory leak
Angular Material pages load 4 times slower in Chrome, and almost not able to load in IE
`What is the expected behavior?
Expect Angular material app to perform similar as angular only app.

Perrformance
Angular Only App:
Chrome: 5.8 seconds load 500 student records
1.4 seconds load 50 student records
IE: 24.98 seconds load 500 student records
2.15 seconds load 50 student records

Angular Material App:
     Chrome:    20.86 seconds load 500 student records
                         2.93 seconds load 50 student records
 IE:               wait 1 hour not able to load 500 students.
             Wait 10 minutes not able to load 200 students
             42.46 seconds to 50 student records
Memory Footage:
1. In general, IE use 1.456 times more memory than chrome
2. Chrome: angular Material use 2.26 times more memory than without it
3. IE: angular Material use 1.73 times more memory than without it

Memory Leak:
Memory leak detected in IE when between two views when angular materiel is used in views.
--switched views 23 times memory increased by 26 MB in IE
$mdDialog cause memory leak in both Chrome and IE
-- open and close dialog 31 times, Chrome memory increased by 27 MB, IE memory increased
by 12 MB

I upload my codes to:
github: https://github.com/gregyichang/MemoryLeak

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd use the [Virtual Repeat](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat) instead of ng-repeat as much as possible. IE especially has a hard time drawing a lot of Angular Material elements that have ripple effects, shadows, and other stuff. That should give you an immediate performance boost. The caveat is that all the rows need to be of equal height to use it.

I'd also only use `layout` and `flex` where they are needed. For example, you can use `<div><span>A</span><span>B</span></div>` instead of `<div layout="row"><div>A</div><div>B</div></div>` and you can use `<div>A</div><div>B</div>` instead of `<div layout="column"><span>A</span><span>B</span>`

Finally, for IE especially, you could disable many of the styles that cause it to slow down. See the CSS posted [on this issue](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/8329), but keep in mind that some of those class names may have changed since that was posted.

Comment: Thanks for the info, maybe I am not clear, but I am not trying search to improve performance here by using virtual repeat or disable animation in IE, . I created two projects in the github link, one project is using angular only and the other one use angular and angular material, to rendering almost identical pages and data, but second project wrap input fields in  md-input-container, this allow increase number watchers by 17+ times.

Comment: If I disable all the animation and ink/ripple  CSS effects for IE, then what is the advantage to use angular material effects? do you have experience with angular 2, does angular material 2 and angular 2 have any improvement on performance, memory footage and memory leak management?